# iPad Mini with earlier version of iOS treats iPhone only apps like iPad apps

Tags: ipad, ios8, ipad-mini

I have an app designed for the iPhone only as the device family within XCode is set to iPhone.  On an iPad Mini running a version prior to iOS 8.2, the app was treated as an iPad app without the (1x)/(2x) button at the bottom.  This was causing crashes and confusion for my end users.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to upgrade to iOS 8.2 or later on the iPad.